# Mocking a React Component using Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to mock one of my components across all tests.  The reason is that it is using a copy of an older version of D3 in a local package, and this D3 has references to "this.document", which errors out when running Jest tests.  This is probably due to the reasons described here: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3970

package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.7.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.7.0",
    "eslint": "5.6.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "13.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "^2.0.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.6.3",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.4.1",
    "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.1.3",
    "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.4.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6"
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom --passWithNoTests"
```

src/setupTests.js

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

import jest from 'jest';
import BarChart from './components/d3/BarChart/BarChart';

jest.mock('BarChart');

BarChart.render.mockResolvedValue(null);
```

However, when I run npm test, I still get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined

   6 |     return d3_arraySlice.call(list);
   7 |   };
>  8 |   var d3_document = this.document;
```

coming from the local D3 package.

My test file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import App from '../App';

it('renders without crashing - deep', () => {
  mount(<App />);
});
```

App has a component which uses BarChart.

Answer (score 1):

### Issue

`import BarChart from './components/d3/BarChart/BarChart';` ends up running code that includes a reference to `this.document` which causes the error.

---

### Solution

The component does not need to be imported in order to mock it.

Either provide a [module factory function](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) as the second parameter to `jest.mock`:

```js
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

jest.mock('./components/d3/BarChart/BarChart', /* provide your module factory function here */);
```

or create a [mock for the component](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules) at `./components/d3/BarChart/__mocks__/BarChart` and simply call `jest.mock` with the path to the component:

```js
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

jest.mock('./components/d3/BarChart/BarChart');
```

Comment: when I used the __mocks__ folder option, it wouldn't find the new module.  I read somewhere about there being problems with nested modules.  For the first option, that's also not working for me.  I opened a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53488371/jest-not-using-manual-mock