# Jest not using manual mock

Tags: jestjs, enzyme, babel-jest

I'm using Create React App.  I created a Jest test that uses a manual mock.  The test renders my App component and I'm trying to mock a nested component.  It's still picking up the original BarChart component.

```
containers/__tests__/App.js
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';

const barChartPath = '../../components/d3/BarChart/BarChart';

describe('App', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    const mockBarChart = require('../../components/d3/BarChart/__mocks__/BarChart').default;
    jest.mock(barChartPath, () => mockBarChart);
  });

  it('renders without crashing - deep', () => {
    const App = require('../App').default;
    mount(<App />);
  });
});
```

I tried using

```
import BarChart from '../../components/d3/BarChart/BarChart';
...
 beforeEach(() => {
    jest.mock(BarChart)
```

but that didn't work either.

I'm using the require statement in the beforeEach due to the issue described in [Manual mock not working in with Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49694366/manual-mock-not-working-in-with-jest)

setupTests.js

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```